# Finding real solutions to $\sin { x=\frac { x }{ 50 } }$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Here's a question that came to my mind,

> Find the number of real valued solutions to the equation $\sin { x=\frac { x }{ 50 }  }$.

I am confused and not able to move on. Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: There really isn't a way to solve questions like this in general, except numerically - approximating the solutions. There is, of course, the obvious $x=0$, but there are a bunch of other solutions.

Comment: Oh, so there's no particular method? :(

Comment: There are lots of different methods for solving the equation numerically, no method to solve it in a closed form, no.

Comment: Best way to solve such an equation is graphical approach.

Comment: @SwapnilDas There is no purely algebraic way to solve this because when you attempt to use complex extensions, it becomes an unsolvable exponential/linear problem, even with the help of the Lambert W function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solutions are in $[-50,50].$ As $\pi\cdot15\simeq47.12,$ using a table of variations for $\sin x-\frac{x}{50}$ (which is an odd function), you can see that there is $15\cdot 2+\underset{\text{the $0$ one}}{\underbrace{1}}=31$ solutions, but you can't get them as real numbers.

Comment: Thanks. Can you think of a pure algebraic solution?

Comment: I guess you didn't believe me when I said, you can't get an algebraic solution. @SwapnilDas

Comment: I believed you, but still in hope...

Comment: No sorry, I agree with Thomas Andrews on this point : trying to make disappear the $\sin$ will make appear $\arcsin,$ etc. Usuals functions can't solve this kind of equations.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for help @ThomasAndrews . Also thanks Baloown.

Comment: Got a similar link (http://ohiorc.org/for/math/stella/problems/problem.aspx?id=631#)

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this problem using a Taylor series expansion to get approximate values:$$\sin(x)=\frac x{50}$$$$\sin(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}=\frac x{1!}-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\ldots$$$$\frac x{1!}-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\ldots=\frac x{50}$$The trick here is to do approximations, not the actual thing.$$\frac{x}{1!}=\frac x{50}\to x_1=0$$$$\frac x{1!}-\frac{x^3}{3!}=\frac{x}{50}\to x_2=0,\pm\frac{7\sqrt{3}}{5}$$Repeating the process, we will get an infinite amount of answers, assuming we allow complex answers.

We will also note $x=0$ will always be a solution, one we can see graphically and within any of the above approximations we want.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the graph of it you can see the fluctuations and meet  $15$  times with $X-axis$ before $π$ on one side. now range of $x$ can be $[-50,50]$ so total solutions are $15+15+1=31$. $+1$ as $0$ is also one of the root.